# Facing Issue with ShowModalDialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, showmodaldialog

I want to display the webpage as a modal popup.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.showModalDialog('NewFile.aspx','Data','left=(screen.width) ? (screen.width - 800) / 2 : 0,top=(screen.height) ? (screen.height - 700) / 2 : 0,width=1000,  height=500, toolbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, location=no, addressbar=no');</script>");
```

While using the above code. I am able to display web page as modal popup, but the issue is that it also opens a third window which is a web page of same name and not a modal popup.

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing the script out to the response use `RegisterStartupScript` instead:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                "detailedresults",
                "<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.showModalDialog('NewFile.aspx','Data','left=(screen.width) ? (screen.width - 800) / 2 : 0,top=(screen.height) ? (screen.height - 700) / 2 : 0,width=1000,  height=500, toolbar=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, location=no, addressbar=no');</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me . Along with your code I had to add the below code in 'NewFile.aspx'... '<base target="_self"/>'